# Thymeleaf & jQuery: script for progress bar works only on first list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, thymeleaf

I have a list on HTML, getting the items from H2DB. In a second column on the same list I display a progress bar. The problem is, that the script works only for the first list item. It's because I give the list-item the ID "actualcost" and the script works with this ID.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${list}">
<td th:text="${item.getActualcost()}" id="actualcost">Actual Cost</td>
<td><div class="progress"><div id="progressPlaceholder"></div>
</div></td>
</tr>
```

The script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var value=$('#actualcost').text(),place=4;
            var progress = '<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'+value+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '+value+'%;"><span class="show">Ranked '+place+' of '+value+'</span></div>';
            $('#progressPlaceholder').empty().append(progress);
        });
        </script>
```

How can I get the value actualcost in the script for each object respectively for each list item?

Comment: IDs need to be unique, jQuery only find the very first element with the ID, use classes instead

Comment: ok, but how do i get the class in the script?

Comment: You use `$('.classname')` to select by classes in jQuery, or is it a thymeleaf specific problem holding you up? You might want to add more code and explanation to your question.

Comment: @user3154108  Ok, that worked. thanks. but still it is working only for the first list item. if i add a second list item, the value is not displayed on the second row but added to the progress bar in the first row. I guess its because of the .text() which simply adds the second value to the existing string. Do i have to write something like "for each..." in the script?